# google apps domain gives diffrent servers when emailing out then mxtoolbox search shows

Tags: spam, mx-record, g-suite, rbl

When I search a domain that uses google apps  I get 10 results mx servers for the domain.

similar to this  alt1.aspmx.l.google.com alt2.aspmx.l.google.com

when I recieve emails I get completly diffrent servers.

We had a problem of one of our RBL stopping a google app company emails. when I lookup the domain I get one list of servers none that match the servers/ip I am getting in our logs.

````
-lj1-f193.google.com>
Jun 12 15:47:16 s5 postfix/smtpd[23553]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lj1-f193.google.com[209.85.208.193]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.208.193] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.208.193; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f193.google.com>
Jun 12 19:33:28 s5 postfix/smtpd[1576]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-ej1-f67.google.com[209.85.218.67]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ej1-f67.google.com>
Jun 12 19:33:28 s5 postfix/smtpd[1576]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-ej1-f67.google.com[209.85.218.67]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ej1-f67.google.com>
Jun 12 19:33:29 s5 postfix/smtpd[1576]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ej1-f67.google.com[209.85.218.67]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.218.67] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.218.67; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ej1-f67.google.com>
Jun 12 20:07:10 s5 postfix/smtpd[3285]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f194.google.com[209.85.208.194]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f194.google.com>
Jun 12 20:07:10 s5 postfix/smtpd[3285]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f194.google.com[209.85.208.194]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f194.google.com>
Jun 12 20:07:10 s5 postfix/smtpd[3285]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lj1-f194.google.com[209.85.208.194]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.208.194] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.208.194; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f194.google.com>
Jun 12 22:42:09 s5 postfix/smtpd[10366]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-ej1-f68.google.com[209.85.218.68]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ej1-f68.google.com>
Jun 12 22:42:09 s5 postfix/smtpd[10366]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-ej1-f68.google.com[209.85.218.68]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ej1-f68.google.com>
Jun 12 22:42:09 s5 postfix/smtpd[10366]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ej1-f68.google.com[209.85.218.68]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.218.68] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.218.68; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ej1-f68.google.com>
Jun 13 00:21:49 s5 postfix/smtpd[423]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f196.google.com[209.85.208.196]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f196.google.com>
Jun 13 00:21:49 s5 postfix/smtpd[423]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f196.google.com[209.85.208.196]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f196.google.com>
Jun 13 00:21:50 s5 postfix/smtpd[423]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lj1-f196.google.com[209.85.208.196]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.208.196] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.208.196; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f196.google.com>
Jun 13 02:29:43 s5 postfix/smtpd[6083]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-wr1-f68.google.com[209.85.221.68]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wr1-f68.google.com>
Jun 13 02:29:43 s5 postfix/smtpd[6083]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-wr1-f68.google.com[209.85.221.68]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wr1-f68.google.com>
Jun 13 02:29:44 s5 postfix/smtpd[6083]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wr1-f68.google.com[209.85.221.68]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.221.68] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.221.68; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wr1-f68.google.com>
Jun 13 04:32:47 s5 postfix/smtpd[11832]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f194.google.com[209.85.208.194]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f194.google.com>
Jun 13 04:32:47 s5 postfix/smtpd[11832]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f194.google.com[209.85.208.194]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f194.google.com>
Jun 13 04:32:48 s5 postfix/smtpd[11832]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lj1-f194.google.com[209.85.208.194]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.208.194] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.208.194; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f194.google.com>
Jun 13 05:57:58 s5 postfix/smtpd[15715]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f195.google.com[209.85.208.195]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f195.google.com>
Jun 13 05:57:58 s5 postfix/smtpd[15715]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lj1-f195.google.com[209.85.208.195]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f195.google.com>
Jun 13 05:57:59 s5 postfix/smtpd[15715]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lj1-f195.google.com[209.85.208.195]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.208.195] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.208.195; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lj1-f195.google.com>
Jun 13 09:00:51 s5 postfix/smtpd[24069]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-wr1-f67.google.com[209.85.221.67]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wr1-f67.google.com>
Jun 13 09:00:51 s5 postfix/smtpd[24069]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-wr1-f67.google.com[209.85.221.67]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wr1-f67.google.com>
Jun 13 09:00:51 s5 postfix/smtpd[24069]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wr1-f67.google.com[209.85.221.67]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.221.67] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.221.67; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-wr1-f67.google.com>
Jun 13 11:22:33 s5 postfix/smtpd[30977]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lf1-f67.google.com[209.85.167.67]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lf1-f67.google.com>
Jun 13 11:22:33 s5 postfix/smtpd[30977]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from mail-lf1-f67.google.com[209.85.167.67]: <googleappscompany@companydomain.com>: Sender address triggers FILTER amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lf1-f67.google.com>
Jun 13 11:22:34 s5 postfix/smtpd[30977]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lf1-f67.google.com[209.85.167.67]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [209.85.167.67] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?209.85.167.67; from=<googleappscompany@companydomain.com> to=<email2us@ourdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lf1-f67.google.com>
Sat 13 Jun 2020 01:18:49 PM EDT```
````

Comment: What exactly do you want help with?

Comment: You seem to have the mistaken assumption that the incoming mail servers a domain uses (the MX records) should be the same servers that are (supposed and allowed to be) sending e-mail for that Domain. That is not the case  at all. (For instance DMARC records govern the latter)

Comment: a  legitimate google email is blocked by rbl using dnsbl.sorbs.net. Does this  mean all google emails using these servers are now blocked?  Does not seem right